# Routing to different pages based on a condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

So we are creating different pages for our application and we need to route from one page to another everytime. We are working on Next.js.

Problem - Say, we have a **Home** page. From this home page, we can either route to **pageA**, and the **pageA** will show different data or different form based on the query parameter passed in the routing, and we need to keep passing that query parameter to upcoming pages to maintain that journey.

Now, as I can see, the usage of **query parameter** is getting a bit complicated as the application is growing.

I would like to know if there is any other way to do routing where we can skip the usage of query parameter and still maintain the state.

Comment: If the query parameter is sent to many subpages, you can use localstorage (or sessionstorage). On the page mounting, you can get the values inside localstorage and set them on the hydration phase.

Comment: @RaphaelEscrig is using localstorage safe and efficient? How is it different other than the face that we won't see query parameters in the url?

Comment: Using localstorage is as safe as query params. With localstorage, it will be easier for you to send values to sub-routes. If you only have one or two sub-routes, query params are ok but with more sub-routes, the code logic / maintainability **could** be annoying (especially because you want to always send the same query params to sub routes).

With localstorage, you can also create a custom hook to get the values / update the value into multiple components.

Comment: @RaphaelEscrig got it... you can write an answer.... I will approve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the query parameter is sent to many subpages, you can use localstorage (or sessionstorage). On the page mounting, you can get the values inside localstorage and set them on the hydration phase.

Using localstorage is as safe as query params. With localstorage, it will be easier for you to send values to sub-routes. If you only have one or two sub-routes, query params are ok but with more sub-routes, the code logic / maintainability could be annoying (especially because you want to always send the same query params to sub routes). With localstorage, you can also create a custom hook to get the values / update the value into multiple components.

Just as a reminder, don't store any sensitive data inside localstorage. I recommend you to read the new Next.js routing system too ! (breaking changes) Read it [here](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/fundamentals).